# How to call and write elements in a list of tuples for a file?

Tags: python, list, function, return

```
def draw(a, xi, yi, ang):
    x = []
    y = []

    while True:
        a = f.readline()
        if a == '':
            break
        else:
            lst = a.split(',')
            lst[:] = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in lst]
            rotate(ang, lst[2])
            forward(xi, yi, lst[0], ang)
            pen(x, y, lst[1])


def forward(cx, cy, lng, ang):
    if float(lng) < 0:
        print('Bad instructions')
        exit(1)
    else:
        xi = cx + float(lng) * cos(radians(float(ang)))
        yi = cy + float(lng) * sin(radians(float(ang)))
        x = [cx, xi]
        y = [cy, yi]
        return x, y
```

In this code the pen function doesn't receive x and y lists from the forward function to operate

This is the just the critical part of the code not the full file

I'm new to programming so I may have over-complicated the code or followed the wrong approach.

Comment: Please , simplify this code and provide a minimalistic example of your problem

Comment: Where is pen function?

Comment: the pen function takes the x and y lists to plot lines with the coordinates from a selected file

Answer (score 1):

You didn't save result of `forward` function, so, as I understand, you should write

```
x, y = forward(xi, yi, lst[0], ang)
```